# How to fetch the string using the substr with garbage characters?

Tags: c++, substring

I have this string, if

```
size_t pos;
pos = eNBSWVerTmp.find("MAC");
```

When I print out the pos, pos 4294967295.

Is there a way I can fetch the string start from **1103**?

```
♦ƒ+Hm.0_MAC_1103_064_00, 21.06.1ÿs7÷l ↕
```

I think garbage chars caused the pos out of range. Thanks in advance.

Comment: std::string doesn't know what "garbage" is. It can even hold null characters. it's little more than an array of characters; just use the correct index.

Comment: I ran this in IDEOne and got the correct position, see: http://www.ideone.com/MPvGa. When you the find() method, check if it returns std::string::npos, which means it didn't find the pattern you sought.

Comment: Is `eNBSWVerTmp` a `std::wstring`? I'm guessing so by the non-ASCII characters. Do you need to find `L"MAC"`?

Comment: std::string eNBSWVerTmp;

Comment: Could there be any non-printing characters within the "MAC" substring?

Comment: What is the string? Post a testcase.

Comment: Is your string specified in your source code literally? Could there be any source code encoding issues? Can you print out the string before you search in it to make sure it has the value that you think it has?

Comment: Kerrek, yes there is an  issue with the string from other tool, but I want to find out how to avoid this kind of garbage chars, so there is a "MAC" in the string, i like to fetch the string started from MAC and avoid those garbage chars at beginning of the string. Anyone can help how to trim/erase those garbage chars? THanks all for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
std::string  test("MAC");
std::copy(test.begin(), test.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
std::cout << "\n";

std::copy(eNBSWVerTmp.begin(), eNBSWVerTmp.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
std::cout << "\n";
```

Now see if the numbers in the top line match a similar sequence of numbers in the bottom line.
I am betting you will not find a match. But you may be able to work out why.

Comment: The result looks like this: 32 50 49 46 48 54 46 49 84 -101 47 87 108 -1 18 13  with this garbage string "♦ƒ+Hm.0_MAC_1103_064_00, 21.06.1ÿs7÷l"

Comment: @AndrewS: Then your string `eNBSWVerTmp` is only this part " 21.06.1ÿs7÷l" if does not contain the string "MAC"

Comment: I see your point, I may be called your statement after problem. I believed you are right, let me try it again. You are fast. Thanks Martin.

Comment: if ostream_iterator<char> then result like this "b a s e   l i n e       =   ♦ ƒ + H m . 0 _ M A C _ 1 1 0 3 _ 0 6 4 _ 0 0 ,   2
  . 0 6 . 1 ╟ â U Å l   ↕"

Comment: with <int>: result: "98 97 115 101 32 108 105 110 101 32 32 32 61 32 4 -97 43 72 109 46 48 95 77 65 6
7 95 49 49 48 51 95 48 54 52 95 48 48 44 32 50 49 46 48 54 46 49 -75 30 -9 -94 1
08 -1 18 13

Comment: so, martin. add a space between those garbage chars, do you think the pos substr will able to find "MAC"

Answer (score 0):

If you start by

```
const size_t pos = eNBSWVerTmp.find("MAC");
```

you know that `pos` indicates where M in MAC can be found (or is std::string::npos if **not** found).

To get some substring starting, say, 4 bytes forward from pos, you can do

```
std::string   substring;

if (pos != std::string::npos)
    substring = eNBSWVerTmp.substr(pos + 4, number_of_bytes);
```

to get the number_of_bytes you want.

Comment: Thanks, Bo. That is what I got, the pos will be showed as out of range or -1 due to garbage chars.

Answer (score 0):

The position `4294967295` isn't a garbage number, it's consistent with what happens if you store a negative number in an unsigned type such as `size_t`. This would be returned by `find` if the substring `MAC` can't be found. So it probably means there's an invisible character inside the substring `MAC`. You might try iterating through the string in an encoding-specific way, and appending characters to a new string (or `std::vector<char>`) only if they're expected characters (i.e. letters, digits, etc.), then finding `MAC` within that.